# Partial CSS styling occuring with HighlightJS

Tags: javascript, css, highlight.js

Greets,
I'm attempting to use highlight.js with an Ajax call: it pulls data from a PHP
script. The `code` element gets populated, but it only styles the background and font color *(verified in devtools)*, syntax highlighting does **not** occur. I have scrubbed the files with `htmlspecialchars` in my PHP script. I do get the correct behavior by typing the code directly into the element. My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>hljs &amp; PHP Proxy</title>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/atelier-forest-dark.min.css">
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <code id="code" class="xml"></code>
        </pre>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mjs-0000B.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var target = document.getElementById('code')

xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status === 200)
        target.textContent = xhr.responseText
        console.log("Ajax request completed")
}

xhr.open('GET','https://localhost/proxy.php',true)
xhr.send(null)

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Window resources loaded");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        hljs.highlightBlock(target)
    }, 50)
});
```

and PHP: it's crap but the only way I could get it to work with CORS...:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/hljs-test.html");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    echo htmlspecialchars($output);
?>
```

I have gone through nearly all of the questions here, but have yet to find a solution. Both HTML and JSON data result in the same behavior so far - and I'm stumped. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the requested output from target.textContent:

```
&lt;!doctype html&gt; &lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt; &lt;header&gt; &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;js/0008.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;/header&gt; &lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `htmlspecialchars($output);` converts `<`, `>` and other symbols to `html entities` that's why highlighter can't recognize your code.
   You have to `echo $output;` instead.
2. You're calling `hljs.highlightBlock(target)` in the wrong place.

Call it in `xhr.onload`, not in `window.onload`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var target = document.getElementById('code')

xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("Ajax request completed")
        target.textContent = xhr.responseText
        hljs.highlightBlock(target)
    }
}

xhr.open('GET','https://localhost/proxy.php',true)
xhr.send(null)

// REMOVE THE FOLLOWING:
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Window resources loaded");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        hljs.highlightBlock(target)
    }, 50)
});
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this in a previous incarnation of my source with the same result which is why I switched to the EventListener, I did try again with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joliet, Another idea is to look closely at your xhr.responseText. What is it look like?

Comment: give me a second and I'll post

Comment: Yup, you were correct! What peeves me is that every search on this site and others suggested to scrub html special characters, check `here` for examples, and this needs to be in the documentation. I will contact the maintainer and hopefully he will update the usage. Thanks so much for your help, it is much appreciated. Shalom.

Comment: @Joliet, happy to help!